# Delphi 5 OpenDialog will return an invalid file name?

Tags: file, delphi, filenames

I try to use the following codes in Delphi 5 to launch an open file dialog:

```
  if OpenDialog.Execute then
    Edit1.Text := OpenDialog.FileName;
```

However, when I try to open a file with a special name, like below:

ZZ- ÖDEME TABLOSU.txt

I find the final text in OpenDialog.FileName and Edit1.Text will become:

ZZ- ?DEME TABLOSU.txt

And of course, the upcoming operations on the file such as open the file with Edit1.Text will also fail.

Why?

Comment: Because of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/character-sets-used-in-file-names) and that D5 does not support unicode.

Comment: Dude, it's the 21st Century, time to embrace Unicode. Either a Delphi upgrade or TNT Unicode controls.

Comment: Although not a solution, you may get a little further by adjusting the system locale accordingly.

Comment: Delphi 5 was release 20 years ago on 10th August 1999. That was the Windows 98, Windows NT 4.0 and early Windows 2000 days. Time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Your ancient Delphi 5 can not handle Unicode characters, as Sertac already said.
Do yourself a favour and use an actual Delphi version with Unicode support (every version >= Delphi 2009).